# (Chrome > 49.0) Flexed container (amongst non-flexed elements) not respecting min-height of child

Tags: google-chrome, flexbox

This code stopped working on recent versions of Chrome (e.g. 52 & 53), but it is still working on Chrome 49 and on up-to-date Firefox versions.

Basically, when the vertical space is little, the container of the textarea shrinks to 0 because all the other non-flexed elements need the space, not respecting the min-height of the textarea.

Any idea how to overcome this?

Thanks!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body {
  margin:0;
}

html, body, app {
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

app {
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 10px;
}

[flexlayout] { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

[flex] {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<app flexlayout>
  <div flex flexlayout>
    <div flex flexlayout style="flex-shrink:0;">
      <!-- NON-FLEXED ELEMENT -->
      <div>pokemon</div>
      <!-- FLEXED ELEMENT -->
      <div flex flexlayout>
        <textarea flex style="min-height:250px;"></textarea>
      </div>
      <!-- NON-FLEXED ELEMENT -->
      <div>
        <p>charmander</p>
        <p>squirtle</p>
        <p>bulbasaur</p>
        <p>pikachu</p>
        <p>growlithe</p>
        <p>slowpoke</p>
        <p>eevee</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</app>
```

Comment: What's wrong with putting the `min-height: 250px` on the container of the textarea?

Comment: Please do not use my answer to fix the problem in your question. Then your question becomes unclear and my answer is invalidated.

Comment: Sorry Oriol, I edited it before I actually read your answer. That min-height: 0 was not supposed to be there. If that min-height: 0 is removed the problem still exists.

Comment: Better yet, what's the point of the container, if it only contains one element (the `textarea`)? https://jsfiddle.net/qcxmcfo4/2/

Comment: @Albert OK, removing `min-height: 0` fixes the problem on firefox, according to [Implied Minimum Size of Flex Items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto). If you still have the problem is probably because your browser does not support that properly, but you can still use `flex-basis: auto; flex-shrink: 0`.

Comment: @Michael_B you got a point there, haha. My example is a poor replica of what I'm trying to do. In my project that `textarea` is preceded by a `label` , and then it makes sense to have that wrapper. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what happens when you these styles on the textarea wrapper:

```css
flex: 1;
min-height: 0;
```

This code does this:

- It sets `flex-shrink: 1`, that it, is allows the flex item to shrink
- It sets `flex-basis: 0`, that is, it ignores the height of the content (the textarea)
- And `min-height: 0` prevents the textarea from enforcing a minimum height to the container when `overflow` is `visible`.

You can either use the default `min-height: auto`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin:0;
}
html, body, app {
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
app {
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 10px;
}
[flexlayout] { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}
[flex] {
  flex: 1;
}
.textarea-wrapper {
  min-height: auto;
}
```

```html
<app flexlayout>
  <div flex flexlayout>
    <div flex flexlayout style="flex-shrink:0;">
      <!-- NON-FLEXED ELEMENT -->
      <div>pokemon</div>
      <!-- FLEXED ELEMENT -->
      <div flex flexlayout class="textarea-wrapper">
        <textarea flex style="min-height:250px;"></textarea>
      </div>
      <!-- NON-FLEXED ELEMENT -->
      <div>
        <p>charmander</p>
        <p>squirtle</p>
        <p>bulbasaur</p>
        <p>pikachu</p>
        <p>growlithe</p>
        <p>slowpoke</p>
        <p>eevee</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</app>
```

or make `flex-basis` be the the height of the contents and prevent shrinking:

```css
flex-basis: auto;
flex-shrink: 0;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin:0;
}
html, body, app {
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
app {
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 10px;
}
[flexlayout] { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}
[flex] {
  flex: 1;
}
.textarea-wrapper {
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<app flexlayout>
  <div flex flexlayout>
    <div flex flexlayout style="flex-shrink:0;">
      <!-- NON-FLEXED ELEMENT -->
      <div>pokemon</div>
      <!-- FLEXED ELEMENT -->
      <div flex flexlayout class="textarea-wrapper">
        <textarea flex style="min-height:250px;"></textarea>
      </div>
      <!-- NON-FLEXED ELEMENT -->
      <div>
        <p>charmander</p>
        <p>squirtle</p>
        <p>bulbasaur</p>
        <p>pikachu</p>
        <p>growlithe</p>
        <p>slowpoke</p>
        <p>eevee</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</app>
```

Comment: Actually, on Chrome 53 I'm still seeing the non-desired behaviour with your first solution. However, your **second solution works**! I tried `flex-shrink: 0;` but not `flex-basis: auto;` at the same time. I guess I still need some flexbox understanding to do. Give me some minutes to try this solution for real and I'll approve the answer.